# java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, path, ionic2

I get this java exception when i build android in CMD and i don't catch why and how to figure this out.

The exception is:

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
```

What can I do ?
(ionic 2 building android windows 10 Home 64 bit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the options in the `_JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable.

For example, on Linux, put the following in your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

Windows:

```
set _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Comment: Check the ans, I did add windows as well

Comment: i have another problem now that he not found java jdk and i have.

Comment: this is the new error:
`Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
Unrecognized option: Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.`